# PHP Regex Replace Two Slashes (//) to New Line

Tags: php, regex, replace, comments

What I'm trying to do here is take a string that might have what would normally be a code comment, and replace that with something else, especially wrapping it in something else. I'm pretty sure the `preg_replace` function would work here, but I don't have an idea on where to start with the Regex. For example:

```
Hello world //this is a comment
Testing //not testing
Test again
```

Would turn into

```
Hello world %//this is a comment%
Testing %//not testing%
Test again
```

`preg_replace('???', '%$1%', $matches);` is as much as I can figure out on my own, any help is much appreciated!

Comment: $0 or \\0 matches the whole thing, $1 is the first back reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
preg_replace('~//.*$~m', '', $str);
```

This will remove everything after (and including) `//` to the end of the line

http://ideone.com/Xhmpd

```
preg_replace('~//.*$~m', 'foo \\0 bar', $str);
```

This will wrap them with `foo bar` around

http://ideone.com/IqkWM

Comment: +1 - Although since PHP 4.0.4 using the form `$0` for references is preferred over the `\\0` form. [See the PHP manual.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: @Richard JP Le Guen: actually I always use `$n` form, not sure what happened now :-S

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$string = "Hello world //this is a comment";
preg_replace('/\/\/.*/', '%$0%', $string);
```